# Bash "reverse" a string

Tags: bash, shell, ip, reverse

```
IP 12.34.56.78
```

I want to find a way to echo this and display the below output

```
78.56.34.12
```

same as the output of `host 12.34.56.78` but without all of the other jargon....

Maybe could just use the host and cut out all of the other stuff. Ideally would liek to avoid the host lookup.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F. '{s="";for (i=NF;i>1;i--) s=s sprintf("%s.",$i);$0=s $1}1' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "12.34.56.78"|awk -F. '{s="";for (i=NF;i>1;i--) s=s sprintf("%s.",$i);$0=s $1}1'
78.56.34.12
```

if you have a prefix `HOST or IP or whatever`:

```
kent$  echo "FOO 12.34.56.78"|awk -F'[. ]' '{s="";for (i=NF;i>2;i--) s=s sprintf("%s.",$i);$0=$1" "s $2}1' 
FOO 78.56.34.12
```

Comment: +1 here. I did not get the idea properly in my answer, so I deleted it. Couldn't beat your `awk` one-liner!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my answer solves your question, Kent seems to have provided a good method for you, but if other people are looking to reverse a BASH string and wind up here this could be useful:

```
echo -n $YOUR_STRING | tac -rs [^-\n]
```